# Dynamic List of Tables in DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm new to MVC and I have following problem:

In my Application, the client will be able to create Tables by himself with the columns/fields he needs.

So my first problem was, how should I design the model class if I don't know how the table is going to look like.
This was solved by putting all fields in a list, so it's dynamic.

```
  public class DynamicData
    {
        public List<decimal> fields { get; set; }

        public DynamicData(String tableName)
        {


        }
    }
```

I also got a static table, which is going to have information about the created tables:

```
  public class Table 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string TableName { set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get;}
    }
```

The next thing was, to put them in the DbContext, which is simple for the static table but not for my dynamic list of created tables:

```
 public class MyDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Table> Tables { get; set; }
        public List<DbSet<DynamicData>> DynamicTables { get; set; }

        public MyDBContext() : base()
        {
            //how do I get my tables now?
        }
    }
```

And now I'm at the point where I don't know how to proceed. I'm not sure if this is best way, but It's my first Idea.

2 Questions:
  1. Is this the best way? Is there a standard solution for that problem (Dynamic amount of tables + dynamic tables)
  2. How do I get my tables in my list in the DbContext and how do I get the fields in my model?